# Get mean of a distribution?

Tags: python

So, I generated a vector `d` of data that follows a normal distribution with some mean and variance.

I want then to calculate a vector s such that each component of it is a function of the type `si=f(di)`.

Then I want to do the mean. Is there in Python any quick way to do that without any cycle?

Comment: Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to perform a function on an entire array for example if I had such a function

```
def f(x):
    return x * 2
```

Then I could use `numpy` as follows

```
>>> d = numpy.array([1,2,6,7])
>>> f(d)
array([ 2,  4, 12, 14])
```

Then to calculate the mean

```
>>> s = f(d)
>>> numpy.mean(s)
8.0
```

Comment: But I get an error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: I want an exponential function

Comment: If I have a function of two vectors, can I write for example simply:
f(x,y)=x*y

and obtin 'd1*d2' ?

Comment: You can [draw samples](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) from a normal distribution with specified mean and variance: `sample = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=5, size=100)`.  To your second question, really no idea what you're saying.